# jquery selector for element within a href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I use Jquery selector to get the text (id) within the 'name' ?

```
<a href="page1.php" id='title' name="<?php echo $res['id'];?>" title="<?php echo $res['title'];?>"  <?php echo $res['sku'];?></a>
```

I tried :

```
$('#title name ').text();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
$('#title').attr('name');
```

The selector you tried:

```
$('#title name').text();
```

Means you're trying to retrieve the text of an element tag `name` (which doesn't exist in HTML) which is a child of an element with `id` title.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$('#title').attr('name');
```